# Enable stack canaries in ios swift

Tags: ios, compiler-flags, penetration-testing, stack-smash

I was looking for a way to enable stack canaries for my ios application in swift but then i found that recent version of xcodes have the flag required to enable stack canaries is enabled by default. So then i was looking for a way to ensure the stack canaries are enabled and as the other sites say i tried with the otool command in terminal($ otool -Iv appName |grep stack_chk) to ensure it and expecting it to return 'stack_chk_guard and stack_chk_fail' flags but it did not return any value/flags. So I then tried setting manually the flag '-fstack-protector-all' under 'other C flags', still I could see no flags with otool command.

[image]

What am I missing here ? or am I misinterpreting something ? how can I assure myself that stack canaries are enabled for my application ?

Answer (score 11):

Looks like you are doing everything correctly. Please double check:

1. You are setting `-fstack-protector-all` flag for main *target* "Other C Flags". Or you are setting it for *project* settings **and** has `$(inherited)` in target build settings.
2. Build your application and in build log (in report navigator, cmd+8) check where is `AppName.app` package
3. `cd path-to-package/AppName.app`
4. use `otool` on binary file: `otool -Iv AppName| grep stack`

Comment: Am doing the exact 4 steps exactly.. no idea whats going wrong.

Comment: @XiOS do you have a single Objective-C file in your project?

Comment: There are few header files included actually @Aleksey

Comment: Ok I just seen that stack canaries are enabled by default for one of my projects in the workspace and not for other.. not sure yet what the reason would be..

Comment: In xCode 9.2 (targeting iOS 11.2), the Build Settings "Other C Flags" seem to also support `fstack-protector-strong` (https://outflux.net/blog/archives/2014/01/27/fstack-protector-strong/) per the grep.

However, in xCode 9.2, the Report Navigator is now mapped to cmd+9.

I am working on an Ionic3 (Cordova 7.1.0) project and after setting these flags and rebuilding the iOS project, all is good.

I found my executable to grep (Foo) in /platforms/ios/Foo.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Foo.app/

Comment: What should the output of the otool command be to indicate stack canaries is enabled vs disabled?